# How to take backup of multiple DB in a specific point of time

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.6, snapshot

My test setup is having 3 databases in postgresql-9.6 instance, 2 DBs consumed by 2 live Web apps.
I am using pg_dump to take hot backup of all databases. In order to keep CPU load under threshold, backup script perform pg_dump in sequence.

```
pg_dump -U postgres -Fc <db-1> > <db-1>.dump
pg_dump -U postgres -Fc <db-2> > <db-2>.dump
pg_dump -U postgres -Fc <db-3> > <db-3>.dump
```

All three database share information like User details, Subscription, Task state, etc.
As the backup is taken in different time period, in the event of Data recovery, the database will end up with inconsistent data across all three DB. One of the DB size is 180GB+ and the dump time for this DB alone would take 30 min.

How to take backup of all databases from a specific time period.

I am not sure how to use the Snapshot feature in postgresql.

Comment: For a database of that size, I would rather use WAL archiving for backups. Or solutions like [pgbackrest](https://pgbackrest.org/), [barman](https://www.pgbarman.org) or [pg_probackup](https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_probackup)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `--snapshot` method (https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-5-feature-highlight-pg-dump-snapshots/), but it might be a bit more complicated than you'd like.

My personal recommendation is to create a cluster-wide backup with `pg_basebackup` (or a third-party app that basically does the same thing, like barman, pg_backrest, etc.)

Comment: I tried steps mentioned in that link, but it throws error for me. I am not sure what logic I am missing here.

ERROR:  invalid snapshot identifier: "0015EBDE-1"

Comment: Can you update your post with the steps that you executed?

Comment: Steps that I followed,
1. BEGIN;
2. SELECT pg_export_snapshot();
3. BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
4. SET TRANSACTION SNAPSHOT '000003F1-1';
5. COMMIT;
6. psql "replication=database dbname=dbname"

After 4th step I got an error as follows,
"ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"

After 5th step I got an error as follows,
"psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "[local]", user "root", SSL off"

Comment: tried above steps after making following changes in pg_hba.conf file,
                                                                                                                                                         # replication privilege.
local   replication all                          trust
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident